# Как перемещать объект под заданным углом?

Tags: c, unity3d, геометрия

Допустим у объекта есть координаты(x,y) и угол, если угол равен 0 градусов то объект движется прямо, если 90, то вправо,180-назад и 270 -влево и 360 - прямо, но что если угол будет не 90 градусов, а 40? Как его тогда перемещать?

Comment: Прямо - это куда? +x? Вправо - +y?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat это не имеет значения , можно за прямо обозначить -x , тогда назад будет +x,а можно и наоборот, можно и с другой осью

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
delta_x = distance * sin(angle)
delta_y = distance * cos(angle)
```

---

не `260`, a `270`

Comment: подождите, если у меня прибавляется только значение по координате y, то x остается неизменным, а мне нужно чтобы он двигался относительно угла

Comment: @НиколайНиколаевич Я не понимаю, что Вы хотите сказать.

Comment: что значит `distance`  в вашем примере?

Comment: @НиколайНиколаевич На какое расстояние Вы хотите переместить объект.

Comment: у меня в коде изменяется только переменная y, каждую секунду ей прибавляется 50, нажимая на стрелочки `влево` и `вправо` изменяется угол, соответственно ваш пример не работает, т.к координата x остается неизменной, можно брать другие координаты, суть же не меняется

Comment: @Yaroslav Не перепутаны, а специально так написаны. Из текста вопроса я вынес твердое убеждение, что "прямо" - это направление вверх, а угол отсчитывается от вертикальной оси. Но может, я в этом и ошибся.

Answer (score 0):

```
float Speed = 1f;
float Ang = 40f;
float Rad = Ang/180f*Math.PI; //перевод в радианы
transform.localPosition += new Vector2(Mathf.Cos(Rad), Mathf.Sin(Rad))*Speed*Time.deltaTime;
```